# path as parameter - ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, parameter-passing

```
<?php
    if (defined('STDIN')) {
        $path= $argv[1];

    } else { 
        $path = $_GET['path'];

    }
    if( isset($path) && ($path!==null) ) {
        $local='/home/www/site/';
        $fullpath = $local . $path;
        var_dump(is_dir($fullpath));
    }
?>
```

If I call it from console , it works as as expected: bool(true).

Called via ajax, it fails:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../inc/is_dir.php',
    data: { path: "a/b" },
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: make sure your ajax url is correct?

Comment: Have you tried to debug yourself first? Did you dump `var_dump($_GET);`?

Comment: Yes, i have. I tried get and post method. Looks good, but both methods fail.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a relative path, check the [network tab in the devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/) where `../inc/is_dir.php` is actually pointing to. There you will also be able to see what kind of error you are getting (e.g. 404, 500, etc.)

Consider using an absolute path, e.g. `/inc/is_dir.php`. You don't want your ajax calls to break if you use the script on a different page.

Comment: I get no error message. I get bool(false) if I try it with ajax.

Comment: I see. Try adding `contentType : "application/json"` to your ajax request and wrap `{ path: "a/b" }` with `JSON.stringify({ path: "a/b" })`

Comment: why would you encapsulate the stringified parameters in an object and then send them through ajax, when jquery passes an OBJECT of parameters? i have tried, but it does not help.